# How can I invert a nullable boolean using SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a way to invert the value of a nullable boolean in MS-SQL. If the boolean field in NULL, I want to consider that the request acts as it was False.

My current request is

```
UPDATE tableName SET booleanColumnName=(1 ^ booleanColumnName) WHERE xxx.
```

This don't work for NULL values as it remains NULL.

Comment: What is the inverse of NULL if not NULL?

Comment: The inverse of NULL is the sound of one hand clapping.

Comment: I like to think of NULL as a representation of "unknown".  It is not a value that can be used in comparisons.  I am holding something in my hand.  You don't konw what it is.  Is it equal in value to the coin you are holding?  You don't know.  We can't tell.  The answer is unkown, or NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try

```
UPDATE tableName SET booleanColumnName = coalesce(1^booleanColumnName,0) WHERE xxx
```

Essentially the same as an IsNull(field, defaultValue) however, you could add more null checks like:

```
coalesce(booleanColumnName, someotherColumn, @default, 0)
```

Here is a test of my methodology

```
create table #test ( a bit, id int identity(1,1) )
insert into #test
select null
union
select 0
union
select 1

select *, coalesce(1^a, 0)
  from #test
```

You will see that it flips the bools and gives you a 0 for null.

Comment: This doesn't find the inverse value

Comment: No such thing as an inverse of null.

Comment: but you are not inverting the boolean values 0 and 1

Comment: Thanks for the QA...fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
ISNULL(booleanColumnName, 0)
```

I.e.:

```
UPDATE tableName SET booleanColumnName = (1 ^ ISNULL(booleanColumnName, 0)) WHERE xxx.
```

Comment: I think your first answer before you edited was correct...putting the 1 ^ will cause the value to be true if the booleanColumnName is null, which I thought was the opposite of what he wanted.  I believe he wants to treat nulls as false?

Comment: @ewahner *was false* should become *is true*

Comment: Okay...but this answer will flip a null to false and then that false to a true...so this answer is wrong as far as I can tell...my `coalesce(1 ^ booleanColumnName, 0)` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
UPDATE tableName SET booleanColumnName=(1 ^ isnull(booleanColumnName, 0)) WHERE xxx.
```

Answer (score 0):

@Giorgi's answer (+1) is the simplest (and first) solution for your code. An alternative that doesn't use wifty math tricks might be a bit clearer:

```
UPDATE tablename
 set booleanColumnName = case isnull(booleanColumnName, 0)
                           when 0 then 1
                           else 0
                         end
```

or even

```
UPDATE tablename
 set booleanColumnName = case booleanColumnName
                           when 1 then 0
                           else 1
                         end
```